# How to use ruby to access and write contents of Azure blobs using Secure Access Signatures?

Tags: ruby, azure

I have several Azure Shared Access Signatures I need to access, list the blobs, and then export the contents.  I am hoping I could just write a simple ruby script and run it on Mac.

Can someone share sample code?  It's basically 'GET" to a URL with a signature, which I think from the command terminal I could use curl, but wasn't sure how to do it using Ruby to make it easier to loop through and maybe extend it later.

I'd be open to a bash script as well.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A quick check on google returned https://github.com/johnnyhalife/waz-storage. Can you check this gem.

Comment: Hi, I checked it out....it seemed good at creating storage, but I couldn't quite use it to access storage and go through different containers...or at least it didn't seem I could....

Comment: Can you check the documentation at http://waz-storage.heroku.com/rdoc/index.html, and see if your requirements are being satisfied.